# When I fetch data from an api json by nextjs, then display it via map function All data is shown on the page except for the image

Tags: next.js, fetch, render

I have a question,

When I fetch data from an api json by nextjs, then display it via map function
All data is shown on the page except for the image

See this error appears on the page

What is mean? What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeEZa.jpg)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Please Provide your code ;-)

Comment: check code , you have tag Image , so you need import Image Next! but i need check your code

Comment: okay, I added image of code error in my post, you can see this error on image now @MarioG8

Comment: Please provide a [mre].